# IIS 10.0 not allowing file upload for .NET Core 2 web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have pored through tons of documentation trying to find out why I cannot upload files in my web application. It's .NET Core 2 hosted on Windows Server 2016 using IIS 10.0.

I have given all the appropriate folder permissions to the application pool user and even other users (MySpecificApplicationPoolUser, IUSR, NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE, IIS_IUSRS, IIS APPPOOL) and I've also tried allowing anonymous authentication in IIS using the application pool user.

I am honestly completely lost and cannot find a solution anywhere. All Google searches lead to assigning permissions to the ApplicationPoolIdentity user but I have done that already and it's still not allowing me to upload a file.

Comment: Hi @DjigStudios, you've told us what the problem you're encountering is, but not what exception you're encountering, nor what the code that's trying to write the file to disk (I'm assuming, perhaps wrongly, that it's the writing to disk that's failing) or process the upload looks like. In order to help you we need as much specific detail about the problem as you can give:)

Comment: ASP.NET Core includes a very good logging by default. If something is not working, you should check the server logs and make sure to check for any errors. If you cannot figure out yourself what the cause of your problem is, then please post relevant log entries in your question so we can try to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The logging helped a lot. I needed to add "FileAccess.Write" to my FileStream call.

Comment: @DjigStudios - You say in your original post that you were able to assign permissions to the ApplicationPoolIdentity. I have done that on my old Windows 2008 server by granting permissions to the Windows-generated IIS AppPool\appPoolName account. But in Windows 2016, I do not see any IIS AppPool\appPoolName account. I cannot figure out how to grant permissions to my web site identity when it uses the IIS built-in ApplicationPoolIdentity. How were you able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in FileStream.
I had:

```
var stream1 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
```

It should have been

```
var stream1 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```